# Switching Circuit from Arduino to Raspberry Pi (Reading Analog Values)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, python

I have wired up this circuit from [learn.parallax](http://https:/https://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino/chapter-6-light-sensitive-8)

[image: QT Charging Circuit]

I have wired this up to an Arduino and it works exactly how I want it too. This is the code that I used to get it working (also from [parallax](https://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino/chapter-6-light-sensitive-7)):

```
void setup()                                 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);                       
} 
 
void loop()                                 
{
  long dTime = rcTime(8);                   
 
  Serial.print("time = ");                   
  Serial.print(dTime);                       
  Serial.println(" us");                     

  delay(1000);                               // 1 second delay
}
                                             // rcTime function at pin 
long rcTime(int pin)                         // ..returns decay time
{                                           
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);                      // Charge capacitor
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);                   // ..by setting pin ouput-high
  delay(1);                                  // ..for 1 ms
  pinMode(pin, INPUT);                       // Set pin to input
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);                    // ..with no pullup
  long time  = micros();                     // Mark the time
  while(digitalRead(pin) == HIGH);           
  time = micros() - time;                    // Calculate decay time
  return time;                               // Return decay time
}
```

I now need to get this to work on my Raspberry Pi which I did not think would be as difficult as it appears. Here is my current code for what I am trying to do:

```
# include CircuitPython libraries
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction
from board import *
import time

port = D18

def RCtime(pin):

    #Declaring pin 18 as output
    sensor = DigitalInOut(pin)
    sensor.direction = Direction.OUTPUT   

    #Charging capacitor by setting pin to HIGH
    sensor.value = True

    #Wait for 1 millisecond
    time.sleep(0.001)

    #Declaring pin 18 as input
    sensor.direction = Direction.INPUT
   
    #Set pin to LOW
    sensor.value = False

    #mark the time
    now = time.monotonic()

    while (sensor.value == True):
         now = time.monotonic() - now
    return now

while True:
    dTime = RCtime(port)
    print('time ' + str(dTime) + ' us')

    time.sleep(1)
```

This does not work. What happens is that I am trying to set the value of a pin as "False" after switching the direction to input which breaks the program. This works in the Arduino software, but not with CircuitPython. If I just comment out the switching direction to input, the program will run but does not work at all as it will display a time and then increment it by 1. I am fairly new to Python, so I am hoping someone with more experience would point me in the right direction!

Comment: Your two while loops that wait for the pin to change are completely different between the C and python code. The C code does nothing with the pin is high. The python code continually resets `now`.

Comment: Are you stuck with Python? You can also try WiringPi if you want it similar to the arduino code.